# find the point in space ahead of current view in opengl on iphone

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I've got some code working to create a 3d view in opengl and then use the device motion to look around within it. i know this is working because i can place 3d cubes in space around me and see that they are in the right places. (i'm just creating them with x/y/z co-ordinates).

The code uses the rotation matrix of the device and then applies it to the various blocks.

```
CMRotationMatrix r = dm.attitude.rotationMatrix;
GLKMatrix4 baseModelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Make(r.m11, r.m21, r.m31, 0.0f,
                                                r.m12, r.m22, r.m32, 0.0f,
                                                r.m13, r.m23, r.m33, 0.0f,
                                                0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f);


float aspect = fabsf(self.view.bounds.size.width / self.view.bounds.size.height);

GLKMatrix4 projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakePerspective(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(65.0f), aspect, kNearZ, kFarZ);

block.effect.transform.projectionMatrix = projectionMatrix;
```

what i want to be able to do is figure out where i'm looking and then create a block out in front of me.

i've had some limited success by creating a vector in one direction, applying the rotation matrix to it and then reading off it's new values. but it only works on some of the directions- when i rotate too far it messes up.

```
GLKVector4 vect = GLKVector4Make(0.0f,0.0f,10.0f,1.0f);

GLKVector4 newVec = GLKMatrix4MultiplyVector4(baseModelViewMatrix,vect);
```

I then read off newVec.x,newVec.y,newVec.z and use them to place the cube.

can someone tell me if i'm on the right track here? is there an easier way to achieve this?

the maths of it all is quite daunting.

UPDATE:

I've had some partial success using

```
 GLKVector3 newVec1 = GLKVector3Make(-r.m22, -r.m33, r.m21);
```

This only works in one lanscape orientation, and also only works in a cylinder around my current location. the up/down axis isn't quite right.

are these parts of the rotation matrix sufficient to get a point anywhere around me?

UPDATE 2:

Thought it might help to post some more code to make it really clear.

This is how everything is getting displayed.

```
//1- get device position
CMDeviceMotion *dm = motionManager.deviceMotion;
CMRotationMatrix r = dm.attitude.rotationMatrix;

GLKMatrix4 baseModelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Make(r.m11, r.m21, r.m31, 0.0f,
                                    r.m12, r.m22, r.m32, 0.0f,
                                    r.m13, r.m23, r.m33, 0.0f,
                                    0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f);

GLKMatrix4 projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakePerspective(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(45.0f), aspect, kNearZ, kFarZ);


//2- work out position ahead of current view
GLKVector3 newVector = GLKVector3Make(-r.m22, -r.m33, r.m21);

//place cube in 3d space- this works fine when just positioning with x,y,z co-ordinates
cube.effect.transform.projectionMatrix = projectionMatrix;
GLKMatrix4 modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Identity;

modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Translate(modelViewMatrix, newVector.x*100, newVector.y*100, newVector.z*100);
modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(baseModelViewMatrix, modelViewMatrix);

cube.effect.transform.modelviewMatrix = modelViewMatrix;
```

Comment: How did you get (-r.m22, -r.m33, r.m21)?

Comment: Also, do you use any "lookAt" or doing some rotations on perspective?

Comment: No I'm not using lookAt. i just rotate everything around using th transformation matrix of the device.

I got to -r.m22, -r.m33, r.m21 based on your answer and then more or less by trial and error, figuring out one at a time.

It seems like there isn't enough information in those 3 variables to describe the complete transformation?

Comment: Check the edit I posted

Answer (score 0):

The vector where you look at should probably be multiplied by inverted matrix. You didn't write what results are you getting but here are a few possible solutions:

1. newVect1 = (r.m13, r.m23, r.m33)
2. newVect2 = (-r.m13, -r.m23, r.m33)
3. multiply (0,0,1) with inverted matrix

**EDIT:** (To add some explanations)

If your baseModelViewMatrix is responsible for rotating all the objects around you then the vector that faces forward (display wise) should be rotated by inverted matrix of baseModelViewMatrix. If it is true that in case that baseModelViewMatrix is identity the correct vector for facing forward is (0,0,1), then just multiply (0,0,1) with inverted matrix (you can simply try that and you even should, just set it to identity and place the object at (0,0,100) or whatever). If it is not, you should find the one that is facing forward and do the same with it.

Concerning the 2nd method I posted `newVect2 = (-r.m13, -r.m23, r.m33)` it is specifically meant in case where (0,0,1) is the forward vector. The idea is that rotation matrix consists of 3 base vectors x,y,z where each row represents one of them respectively (it always works for creating rotation matrix but might not reversibly). If the 3rd row does represent the z base vector then vector (0,0,1) will be transformed to (r.m13, r.m23, r.m33) and the one you seem to be facing is the vector that is mirrored through its normal (0,0,1). The operation for that would be R' = normal*(2*dot(normal, R)) - R and for the case where normal is (0,0,1) and R is (r.m13, r.m23, r.m33), the result R' is (-r.m13, -r.m23, r.m33). Just as a note here it might be turned around and the z base vector is (r.m31, r.m32, r.m33).

In any case, if 3rd option does not work neither will the 2nd and the problem for that is probably that (0,0,1) is not the forward vector for identity.

Comment: Hi there. thanks for your answer. how do i use this? if i add the code as is i get a code error. do i need to use GLKVector3Make?

Comment: Whatever vector type suits you better, GLKVector3Make or GLKVector4Make(..., 1)

Comment: i've updated the question to add some more explanation. thanks for your help!